# Open annotation vs Closed annotation for business writing

Tags: business-language

For business writing (mail and letters) which one is more preferred annotation?

Open annotation:-
Hi James
......
Thanks
Vikas

Closed annotation:-
Hi James,
......
Thanks,
Vikas

Comment: I prefer leaving the commas in.

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree.

Comment: I remember having read somewhere very recently "strictly no comma at the end of the salutation" -- why, I never asked. Google "no comma after salutation"

Comment: This question belongs on [writers.se]

Comment: http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/essaysandletters/letters

Comment: "The Chicago Manual of Style has basically thrown up its hands: ... *In e-mail greetings, do as you please.* ... How to punctuate an email salutation is a nicety that only grammar geeks would fret over. But fret we do. At least some of us. What about you?” http://blog.editors.ca/?p=3605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a "preferred" style. It's a matter of choice and which style guide you follow.

For instance, [the Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/653/01/) suggests using a colon rather than a comma:

> Dear James:
>   . . .

Or, if you put a comma after *hello*:

> Hello, James:
>   . . .

On the other hand, an editing mentor of mine used a comma when addressing me:

> Hello, Jason,
>    . . .

My *own* style has historically been to use just a name and a comma:

> James,
>    . . .

But, from my personal experience, whether you use a comma or a colon (and whether you put a comma after *hello* or not, or you use more than just a name), the use of either a comma or a colon is much more common than not using anything at all.